# What are the ways to solve my iPhone power drainage problem?

Tags: iphone, battery

I am using iPhone 5s with iOS 7.1.1

I have a problem from 3 days ago. The battery keeps draining and the phone keeps warm in the whole day.

I found that mstreamd keeps starting every minute. From some online communities, it seems like the source of the problem. Their solution is to JB it and remove mstreamd, but I don't want to do so.

Steps to reproduce the symptom:

```
1. I don't know
```

Steps I have tried:

```
1. reboot
2. reset the iPhone
3. Disable iCloud
4. Disable photostream sync and syncing over Wifi
```

All can't help.

How to solve this? Thanks.

[image]

Reference:

http://forums.macrumors.com/archive/index.php/t-1716660.html
http://www.reddit.com/r/jailbreak/comments/28n3vn/solved_crazy_battery_drain_may_apply_to_other/

Comment: 1) "From some online communities" --> it would be helpful to cite where. 2) **Disable photostream sync and syncing over Wifi [to your computer]** Is there an improvement? 3) General note, follow [this user tip](https://discussions.apple.com/docs/DOC-7071) I posted over at ASC

Comment: What type of battery life were you getting before 3 days ago vs now? Anything you've changed before 3 days ago vs now?

Comment: drop ~25% after 8 hours vs drop 100% after 8 hours. Not much difference in terms of usage.

Comment: Could you look sorted by the CPU time, to see who is actually using it for long time. The mstream is a drop in a bucket.